# Invalid procedure call error in MS Access Sum

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use the following SQL select query in MS Access to generate result on large input data:

```
SELECT "1.01" AS Item
    ,"Name" AS Test
    ,Count([Item]) AS [Count]
    ,Sum(IIf([Results] = "Invalid", 1, 0)) AS [# Invalid]
FROM [Test 1-01]
GROUP BY "1.01"
    ,"Name"
    ,"Yes";
```

I got an 'Invalid Procedure call' error. I traced down the part of the query that caused the error is

```
Sum(IIf([Results]="Invalid",1,0)) AS [# Invalid]
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this error ?

Comment: `Test 1-01` table is a local Access table or linked one? If linked, then which type of table - Access or ODBC? You don't need `GROUP BY` part as soon as all columns are constant

Comment: Why do you create fields with literal text "1.01" and "Name"? Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention nor reserved words as names.

Comment: @Sergey S.  Test 1-01 table is a local Access table that I loaded large amount of data. There's a column called 'Results', which should have values such as 'Valid', 'Invalid'.   I want to generate the total number of records and the total number of 'Invalid' in the 'Results' column. I got error 'Invalid procedure call' on the part of query 'Sum(IIf([Results] = "Invalid", 1, 0)) AS [# Invalid]' for some data load.  it works if I remove the part  'Sum(IIf([Results] = "Invalid", 1, 0)) AS [# Invalid]' .  I guess it has something to do with the 'Results' column data.

Comment: @June7, this is an example.

Comment: How big is the database file? If the size approaches 2 gigs, it may give errors. Also, such kind error may be caused by damaged records in the table. Try to copy the data from this table to another one using query, it will give the same error in case of broken records.

Answer (score 0):

@Sergery S. You're right. I found the problem was due to one damaged row data. It works fine again after I removed that row. Thahks again.